# Reset an entire node InfoPath 2007

Tags: infopath-2007

I have an InfoPath Form built.  What I am looking to do is have a reset button that clears and entire node of populated data.  I have seen a few solutions out there but this seems like a relatively simple request of a page.  Is there a quick way to reset an entire node to its default configuration?

Thanks in Advance!

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have solved it.

```
private void ClearNode(XPathNavigator nodeToClear)
{
    if (nodeToClear.HasChildren)
    {
        nodeToClear.MoveToFirstChild();
        do
        {
            ClearNode(nodeToClear);
        } while (nodeToClear.MoveToNext());
        nodeToClear.MoveToParent();
    }
    else
    {
        nodeToClear.SetValue(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

After that you just call whatever node you want cleared and pass it in as an XPathNavigator and away you go.  It solved everything I was storing but I am curious how it would handle resetting fields with default values like a boolean or something.